# How to remove specific feature in feature collection under geojson source in a places layer?

Tags: mapbox

I got this:

```
map.addLayer({
  "id": "places",
  "type": "symbol",
  "source": {
    "type": "geojson",
    "data": {
      "type": "FeatureCollection",
      "features": features
    }
  },
  "layout": {
    "icon-image": "{icon}-15",
    "text-field": "{title}",
    "text-font": ["Open Sans Semibold", "Arial Unicode MS Bold"],
    "text-offset": [0, 0.6],
    "text-anchor": "top"
  }
});
```

Where `features` is array of objects like this:

```
{
  "id": SOME_ID,
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "title": SOME_TITLE,
    "icon": "monument"
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": SOME_COORDINATES
  }
}
```

I want to delete this specific feature, **NOT THE WHOLE places LAYER**, how can it be done?

I have tried to create for each feature, a designated layer with predefined ID, but 
when tried to remove it using `map.removeLayer(SOME_ID)` this told me that the 
layer id does not exist.

How to delete specific geojson feature from feature collection in mapbox, without delete the wole 
layer, just the json data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to hide the feature on the map, then you don't have to remove it from the source. You can filter this feature out using [`filter`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#other-filter), so it wouldn't be rendered on the map.

Consider example:

```
    map.addLayer({
      id: 'points',
      type: 'circle',
      source: {
        type: 'geojson',
        data: {
          type: 'FeatureCollection',
          features: [
            {
              type: 'Feature',
              id: 1,
              properties: {},
              geometry: {
                type: 'Point',
                coordinates: [127.61718749999999, 66.51326044311185]
              }
            },
            {
              type: 'Feature',
              id: 2,
              properties: {},
              geometry: {
                type: 'Point',
                coordinates: [79.1015625, 72.50172235139388]
              }
            },
            {
              type: 'Feature',
              id: 3,
              properties: {},
              geometry: {
                type: 'Point',
                coordinates: [61.17187499999999, 31.952162238024975]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      filter: ['!=', '$id', 3]
    });
```

This will render all features except feature with id=3.

You can also set this kind of filters using [`map.setFilter`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#setfilter) method.

```
map.setFilter('my-layer', ['==', 'name', 'USA']);
```

**Edit**:

If you really want to remove a specific feature from the source, you can filter this feature from the `features` array and update the source using [setData](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#geojsonsource#setdata):

```
map.getSource('places').setData({
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  features
});
```

Comment: Probably not the official way, but this can do it. How to remove this filter?

Comment: It is the official way. To remove the filter, you can unset it with

map.setFilter('my-layer', undefined);